# who to wirte a correct pull function

Tags: c++

I want to implement pull-stream by C++ , reference "https://github.com/pull-stream/pull-stream/blob/master/pull.js"

But I got this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'pull'
note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument 'stream', but 3 arguments were provided
note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
```

my code:

```
template <typename T>
auto values(T && begin, T && end){
    return [&](bool abort, auto cb){

        if(begin != end){
            cb(false, *begin++);
        }
        else{
            cb(true, *begin);
        }
    };
};
```

values, source function.

```
template <typename T, typename R>
auto log(R read){

    std::function<void (bool, T)> more = [&](bool done, T val){
        if(!done){
            cout << val << endl;
            read(false, more);
        }
    };

    read(false, more);
}
```

log, sink function.

```
template <typename T>
T pull(T && stream){
    return stream;
}
```

```
template <typename R, typename S>
auto pull(R && read, S && sink){
    return sink(read);
}
```

pull(source, sink)

```
template <typename R, typename T, typename... Ts>
auto pull(R && read, T && through, Ts... args){
    return pull(through(read), args...);
}
```

pull(source, through..., sink)

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);

    auto vals = values(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    auto mapper = [&](int val){return val * 2;};
    auto timesTwo = Map<int>(mapper);

    pull(vals, timesTwo, log); // error, how to write a correct `pull` function, make this line run ok
}
```

link source->through->sink. work wrong.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);

    auto vals = values(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    auto mapper = [&](int val){return val * 2;};
    auto timesTwo = Map<int>(mapper);

//    pull(vals, timesTwo, log);

    auto newVals = pull(vals, timesTwo, timesTwo); // work ok

    bool ended = false;
    do {
        newVals(false, [&](bool done, auto val){
            ended = done;
            if (ended) {
                return;
            }
            cout << val << endl;
        });
    } while (!ended);
}
```

link source->through->through.
work right. output 4 8

[Correct Eample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba79c63a338f0b8e)

Comment: The "who" would be you :).  Can you explain why you thought your code was correct?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: pull(source, through, through) will work right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `log` is a function template, and there's nothing to deduce it's `T` and `R` from, so the variadic `pull` overload doesn't match.

It would work if `log` were a function object, e.g.

```
auto log = [](auto read) {

    std::function<void (bool, int)> more = [&](bool done, int val){
        if(!done){
            std::cout << val << std::endl;
            read(false, more);
        }
    };

    read(false, more);    
};
```

or if you wrapped your `log` template in a lambda

```
pull(vals, timesTwo, [](auto read) { log<int>(read); });
```

Comment: I have another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59801283/implement-pull-stream-by-c-with-segmentation-fault?noredirect=1#comment105743610_59801283 ) like this, can you help me