# implement pull-stream by C++ with Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I want to implement pull-stream by C++ , reference "https://github.com/pull-stream/pull-stream/blob/master/pull.js"

But I got error: Segmentation fault, when I link read -> (through->through) -> sink

my code

```
template <typename T>
auto values(T && begin, T && end){
    return [&](bool abort, auto cb){

        if(begin != end){
            cb(false, *begin++);
        }
        else{
            cb(true, *begin);
        }
    };
}
```

source/read, contain values.

```
template <typename T, typename M>
auto Map(M mapper) {

    return [&](auto & read){
        return [&](bool abort, auto cb){
            read(abort, [&](bool end, T val){
                if(end)
                    cb(true, val);
                else
                    cb(false, mapper(val));
            });
        };
    };
}
```

Map generate a through with a mapper.

```
template <typename T, typename R>
auto log(R && read){

    std::function<void (bool, T)> more = [&](bool done, T val){
        if(!done){
            cout << val << endl;
            read(false, more);
        }
    };

    read(false, more);
}
```

sink, consumer values from source.

```
template <typename T>
T pull(T && stream){
    return std::forward<T>(stream);
}

// return void/read
// read -> sink
// read -> through
template <typename R, typename S>
auto pull(R && read, S && sink){
    return sink(read);
}
```

pull, link read -> through or through -> through

```
// return read
// read -> through -> ...
template <typename R, typename T, typename... Ts>
auto pull(R && read, T && through, Ts &&... args){
    return pull(through(read), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

pull, link source -> through -> sink

```
// return through
// through -> through
// through -> sink
template <typename T, typename R>
auto pull2(T && through1, R && through2){
    return [&](auto & read) {
        return pull(read, through1, through2);
    };
}
```

pull, link through -> through or through -> sink

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    auto begin = vec.begin();
    auto end = vec.end();

    auto logInt = [&](auto read) { log<int>(read); };
    auto vals = values(begin, end);

    auto mapper = [&](int val){return val * 2;};
    auto timesTwo = Map<int>(mapper);

    auto valsTimes = pull(vals, timesTwo);

    auto timesFour = pull2(timesTwo, timesTwo);

    auto doubleSink = pull2(timesTwo, logInt);

    pull(vals, timesTwo, timesTwo, logInt); // work right
   // pull(vals, timesFour, logInt); // error, Segmentation fault, 
                                     // may be pull/pull2/Map function has bug, but I don't known where, 
                                     //how to correct it to make this line run ok

    return 0;
}
```

who to make this line `pull(vals, timesFour, logInt);` run ok?

[Code Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04194a4258f24236)

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us in the question itself, making it self-contained.

Comment: Can you post all code snippets in one code snippet, for example with comments, so that it's easy to copy and test it? Can you add relevant `#include`s? Can you create a compilable [MCVE]. What exactly is your question?

Comment: code example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04194a4258f24236